# Class 'setasign\Fpdi\FpdfTpl' not found

Tags: php, fpdf, fpdi

everyone I am working with fpdf an fpdi, is my first work and I have a problem. I can not edit a pdf. This is the problem. thanks

> Class `setasign\Fpdi\FpdfTpl` not found in `C:\wamp\www\Ale\fpdi\src\Fpdi.php`

```
    use setasign\Fpdi\Fpdi;

require_once('fpdf/fpdf.php');
require_once('fpdi/src/Fpdi.php');
require_once('fpdi/src/autoload.php');

// initiate FPDI
$pdf = new Fpdi();
// add a page
$pdf->AddPage();
// set the source file
$pdf->setSourceFile('documento.pdf');
// import page 1
$tplIdx = $pdf->importPage(1);
// use the imported page and place it at position 10,10 with a width of 100 mm
$pdf->useTemplate($tplIdx, 10, 10, 100);

// now write some text above the imported page
$pdf->SetFont('Helvetica');
$pdf->SetTextColor(255, 0, 0);
$pdf->SetXY(30, 30);
$pdf->Write(0, 'This is just a simple text');

$pdf->Output('newDoc.pdf','F');
```

Answer (score 0):

[You cannot edit a PDF with FPDI!](https://www.setasign.com/support/faq/fpdi/can-i-edit-a-pdf-document-with-fpdi/#question-82)

Remove the line:

```
require_once('fpdi/src/Fpdi.php');
```

...to give the later required autoload function a chance.

Comment: i did but still not working..this is the new error Class 'setasign\Fpdi\Fpdi' not found in C:\wamp\www\Ale\index.php

Comment: the strange is when i try the code at home, work fine. maybe is for the version of PHP?. im using 5.4.3

Comment: You should urgently upgrade your PHP environment to an up to date version! FPDI 2.x was tested on PHP 5.6 and up.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not related to this exact question but I had a similar situation in my Lumen project...
I resolved it by reintsalling vendor files. I hope if someone is facing similar situation, I hope this helps.